# how to dry up 2 almost identical methods that are used in almost every controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, dry

In most of my rails controllers I use 2 methods to set layout and sub_layout
Feels messy, lot of repeat == not dry ( methods in almost every controller).

*Im looking for some constructive suggestions on how to dry this code*

**Profile_controller.rb:**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  layout        :resolve_layout

    def resolve_layout
        case action_name
          when "show"
            if user_signed_in?
              "application"
            else
              "application"
            end
          when "get_info"
            "modal"
          else
            "application"
        end
      end

      def sub_layout
        case params[:action]
          when "index"
            if user_signed_in?
              "left"
            else
              "right"
            end
          when "show"
            if user_signed_in?
              "left"
            else
              "right"
            end
          else
            "left"
        end
      end

      ..etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class LayoutHandler < Struct.new(:action, :user_signed_in)

  def resolve
    case action
    when "get_info" then "modal"
    else "application"
    end
  end

  def sub
    case action
    when "index", "show" then user_signed_in? ? "left" :"right"
    else "left"
    end
  end
end
```

In your controller:

```
layout :resolve_layout

def resolve_layout
  LayoutHandler.new(params[:action], user_signed_in?).resolve
end
```

Comment: could you please explain a bit more what this does and how it works? kind regards. For example where to store handlers

Comment: it does the same as your code, just abstracted outside of your controller. I'd put this in `lib/controller_helpers`

Comment: ok clear, do you require the file inside your controllers at the top or is it "auto"loaded in rails 3?

Comment: and why not place it in /app/helpers seems more logic place to have this situated?

Comment: a helper is supposed to be a module which functions are used in views. So nope for me. But feel free